# Count of binary numbers from 1 to n

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary

I want to find the number of numbers between 1 and n that are valid numbers in base two (binary).

1 ≤ n ≤ 10^9

For example, suppose n is equal to 101.

```
Input: n = 101
```

In this case, the answer is 5

```
Output: 1, 10, 11, 100, 101 -> 5
```

Another example

```
Input: n = 13
Output: 1, 10, 11 -> 3
```

Here is my code...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, c = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        int temp = i;
        bool flag = true;
        while(temp != 0) {
            int rem = temp % 10;
            if (rem > 1)
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            c++;
        }
    }
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

**But I want more speed.

(With only one loop or maybe without any loop)**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surprise, but 101 binary is 5 decimal and that's not coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Details:**
In each step, if the digit was one, then we add 2 to the power of the number of digits we have.
If the number was greater than 1, then all cases are possible for that number of digits, and we can also count that digit itself and change the answer altogether (-1 is because we do not want to calculate the 0).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int n, res = 0, power = 1;
    cin >> n;

    while(n != 0) {
        int rem = n % 10;
        if (rem == 1) {
            res += power;
        } else if (rem > 1) {
            res = 2 * power - 1;
        }
        n /= 10;
        power *= 2;
    }
    cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The highest binary number that will fit in a d-digit number `d1 d2 ... dn` is
`b1 b2 ... bn` where

```
bi = 0 if di = 0, and
bi = 1 otherwise.
```

A trivial implementation using `std::to_string`:

```
int max_binary(int input) {
    int res = 0;
    auto x = std::to_string(input);
    for (char di : x) {
        int bi = x == '0' ? 0 : 1;
        res = 2 * res + bi;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This answer is almost correct: if we see a base-10 digit of input that's 2 or larger, the answer should add 2^length(remaining from to_string(input)) - 1 to res and return. Try this code for input = 20, which should be 3

Comment: Well, you have the approach. What's stopping you?